# Tanh-sinh quadrature numerical integration method converging to wrong value

Tags: python, python-2.7, numerical-integration

I'm trying to write a Python program to use Tanh-sinh quadrature to compute the value of:

[image: an integral]

but although the program converges to a sensible value with no errors in every case, it's not converging to the correct value (which is pi for this particular integral) and I can't find the problem.

Instead of asking for a desired level of accuracy, the program asks for the number of function evaluations wanted, to make comparisons of convergence with simpler integration methods easier. The number of evaluations needs to be an odd number as the approximation used is

[image]

Can anyone suggest what I might have done wrong?

```
import math

def func(x):
    # Function to be integrated, with singular points set = 0
    if x == 1 or x == -1 :
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 / math.sqrt(1 - x ** 2)

# Input number of evaluations
N = input("Please enter number of evaluations \n")
if N % 2 == 0:
    print "The number of evaluations must be odd"
else:
    print "N =", N  

# Set step size
h = 2.0 / (N - 1)
print "h =", h

# k ranges from -(N-1)/2 to +(N-1)/2
k = -1 * ((N - 1) / 2.0)
k_max  = ((N - 1) / 2.0)
sum = 0

# Loop across integration interval
while k < k_max + 1:

    # Compute abscissa
    x_k = math.tanh(math.pi * 0.5 * math.sinh(k * h))

    # Compute weight
    numerator = 0.5 * h * math.pi * math.cosh(k * h)
    denominator = math.pow(math.cosh(0.5 * math.pi * math.sinh(k * h)),2)
    w_k =  numerator / denominator

    sum += w_k * func(x_k)

    k += 1

print "Integral =", sum
```

Comment: on a completely different note, legendre-gauss quadrature might be faster (using the tabular data from http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/legendre-gauss.html or something for high precision)

Comment: What value is it converging to?

Comment: You should change the singular points to be x<=-1, x >= 1. You won't fall right on the integer values due to round off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, Scipy has numerical integration functions

For instance,

```
from scipy import integrate
check = integrate.quad(lambda x: 1 / math.sqrt(1 - x ** 2), -1, 1)
print 'Scipy quad integral = ', check
```

gives the result

> Scipy quad integral =  (3.141592653589591, 6.200897573194197e-10)

where the second number in the tuple is the absolute error.

That said, I was able to get your  program to work with some tuning (although this is just an initial attempt):

1) Set the step size h to 0.0002 (roughly 1/2^12) as suggested by [this paper](http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/dhb-tanh-sinh.pdf)

But note - the paper actually suggests altering the step size iteratively - with a fixed step size you will reach a point where the sinh or cosh grow too large for large enough values of *kh*. It would probably be better to attempt an implementation based on that paper's approach.

But sticking to the question at hand,

2) Make sure  you set enough iterations for the integration to really converge , i.e. enough iterations that math.fabs(w_k * func(x_k)) < 1.0e-9

With these tunings, I was able to get the integration to converge  to the correct value of pi to 4 significant figures using > 30000 iterations.

For instance with 31111 iterations, the value of pi computed was 3.14159256208

Example code with modifications (note I replaced sum with thesum, sum is the name of a Python built-in function):

```
import math

def func(x):
    # Function to be integrated, with singular points set = 0
    if x == 1 or x == -1 :
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 / math.sqrt(1 - x ** 2)

# Input number of evaluations
N = input("Please enter number of evaluations \n")
if N % 2 == 0:
    print "The number of evaluations must be odd"
else:
    print "N =", N  

# Set step size
#h = 2.0 / (N - 1)
h=0.0002 #(1/2^12)
print "h =", h

# k ranges from -(N-1)/2 to +(N-1)/2
k = -1 * ((N - 1) / 2.0)
k_max  = ((N - 1) / 2.0)
thesum = 0

# Loop across integration interval
actual_iter =0
while k < k_max + 1:

    # Compute abscissa
    x_k = math.tanh(math.pi * 0.5 * math.sinh(k * h))

    # Compute weight
    numerator = 0.5 * h * math.pi * math.cosh(k * h)
    dcosh  = math.cosh(0.5 * math.pi * math.sinh(k * h))
    denominator = dcosh*dcosh
    #denominator = math.pow(math.cosh(0.5 * math.pi * math.sinh(k * h)),2)
    w_k =  numerator / denominator

    thesum += w_k * func(x_k)
    myepsilon = math.fabs(w_k * func(x_k))
    if actual_iter%2000 ==0 and actual_iter > k_max/2:
        print "Iteration = %d , myepsilon = %g"%(actual_iter,myepsilon)


    k += 1
    actual_iter += 1

print 'Actual iterations = ',actual_iter
print "Integral =", thesum
```

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions, and I can reproduce your value of pi fine. However if I enter N greater than about 69000 then I get the error Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Tanh Sinh.py", line 36, in <module>
    csh = math.cosh(u)
OverflowError: math range error  Is there anything I can do about this, as it's limiting the maximum accuracy I could achieve?

Comment: With fixed stepsize h, you are going to run into that point of diminishing returns because of the exponential growth of sinh and cosh with increasing absolute values of kh. The paper I linked suggests instead altering the stepsize as you iterate, probably you should implement based on that suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Using the multiprecision library `mpmath`:

```
from mpmath import *

mp.dps = 100

h = mpf(2**-12);

def weights(k):
    num = mpf(0.5)*h*pi*cosh(k*h)
    den = cosh(mpf(0.5)*pi*sinh(k*h))**2
    return (num/den)

def abscissas(k):
    return tanh(mpf(0.5)*pi*sinh(k*h))

def f(x):
    return 1/sqrt(1 - mpf(x)**2)

N = 20000

result = 0
for k in range(-N, N+1):
    result = result + weights(k)*f(abscissas(k))

print result - pi
```

gives for the error

```
-3.751800610920472803216259350430460844457732874052618682441090144344372471319795201134275503228835472e-45
```

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the problem might be due to range and step size. I've modified the code
so you can put in the range and step size separately and rewritten some of the maths. It seems to give the right answers. Try for example 5 and 0.1 as inputs.

A particular problem is calculating `math.cosh(0.5 * math.pi * math.sinh(k * h))` as `k * h` get large `math.sinh(k * h)` grows exponentially and calculating math.cosh of that can be hard. 
    import math

```
def func(x):
#    return 1   # very simple test function
    # Function to be integrated, with singular points set = 0
    if x == 1 or x == -1 :
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 / math.sqrt(1 - x ** 2)

# Input number of evaluations
N = input("Please enter max value for range \n")
    print "N =", N
h = input("Please the step size \n")
print "h =", h

k = -N
k_max = N
sum = 0
count = 0
print "k ", k , " " , k_max

# Loop across integration interval
while k < k_max + 1:

    # Compute abscissa
    v = k
    u = math.pi * 0.5 * math.sinh(v)
    x_k = math.tanh(u)
    #print u
    # Compute weight 
    numerator = 0.5 * math.pi * math.cosh(v)
    csh = math.cosh(u)
    denominator = csh*csh
    w_k =  numerator / denominator
    print k, v, x_k , w_k
    sum += w_k * func(x_k)
    count += 1
    k += h      # note changed
res = sum * h
print "Integral =", sum * h
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to realise that +1 and -1 are singular points of your integrand, `f(x)-->+infinity` as `x-->+1,-1`. As such, you can use your favourite quadrature formula *away* from the boundary points, but you have to work out a special quadrature based on a *local expansion* of `f(x)` in a neighbourhood of them.

Sketch of the approach:

1. Pick some `epsilon<<1`.
2. Decompose the integral `I` into smooth and singular parts:

   - `I_smooth` is the integral inside `[-1+epsilon, 1-epsilon]`
   - `I_singular` are the integrals from `[-1, -1+epsilon]` and `[1-epsilon, 1]`.
3. Apply your standard quadrature rule inside the interval `[-1+epsilon, 1-epsilon]`
   to get `I_smooth`.
4. Perform a local expansion around the singular points (e.g. *x=1*):

   ```
   f(x) = 1/sqrt(1-x) * (a0 + a1*(1-x) + a2*(1-x)^2 + ...)

        = f0(x-1) + f1(x-1) + f2(x-1) + ..
   ```

   which is just a Taylor expansion about `x=1` of `f(x)*sqrt(1-x)` premultiplied by `1/sqrt(1-x)`. (Unfortunately you have to do some math and work out the Taylor expansion
   unless you have Mathematica or you can find it tabulated somewhere.)
5. Each single term `fn(x-1) = an*(1-x)^n/sqrt(1-x`) can be integrated exactly (it's just a power function). Let `Fn` be the integral of `fn` from `1-epsilon` to `1`. 
   Approximate `I_singular = F0 + F1 + F2 + ...` up to the order you want.
6. Finally:

   ```
   I = I_smooth + I_singular
   ```

Note: to push accuracy you should not make `epsilon` too small because the blow-up of the integral makes the problem numerically ill-conditioned, but rather increase the order of the Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/32812/3980) on scicomp:

There are a bunch of pitfalls when it comes to tanh-sinh quadrature, one being that the integrand needs to be evaluated *very* closely to the interval boundaries, at distances less than machine precision, e.g., `1.0 - 1.0e-20` in the original example. When this point is evaluated, it rounds to `1.0` at which `f` has a singularity, and anything can happen. That's why you have you'll first have to transform the function such that the singularities sit at 0.

In the case of `1 / sqrt(1 - x**2)`, this is `1 / numpy.sqrt(-x**2 + 2*x)` for both the left and the right singularity. With [tanh_sinh](https://github.com/nschloe/tanh_sinh) (a project of mine), one then gets

```py
import numpy
import tanh_sinh

# def f(x):
#    return 1 / numpy.sqrt(1 - x ** 2)

val, error_estimate = tanh_sinh.integrate_lr(
      lambda x: 1 / numpy.sqrt(-x**2 + 2*x),  # = 1 / sqrt(1 - (x-1)**2)
      lambda x: 1 / numpy.sqrt(-x**2 + 2*x),  # = 1 / sqrt(1 - (-(x-1))**2)
      2,  # length of the interval
      1.0e-10
      )
print(val, val - numpy.pi)
```

```
3.1415926533203944 -2.693987255497632e-10
```