# Different results while integrating Chebyshev weight function using different quadratures

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

Can someone explain the following behaviour I observe while integrating the [Chebyshev weight function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html) using 3 different routines and 2 different representations of the exponent? The expected answer is Pi in each case:

```
from scipy.integrate import quadrature, quad, fixed_quad

print fixed_quad(lambda x: 1/(1 - x**2)**(1/2), -1, 1)
print fixed_quad(lambda x: 1/(1 - x**2)**(0.5), -1, 1)

print quadrature(lambda x: 1/(1 - x**2)**(1/2), -1, 1) 
print quadrature(lambda x: 1/(1 - x**2)**(0.5), -1, 1)

print quad(lambda x: 1/(1 - x**2)**(1/2), -1, 1)
print quad(lambda x: 1/(1 - x**2)**(0.5), -1, 1)
```

which gives

```
(2.0000000000000009, None)
(2.8254100794589787, None)

(1.9999999999999996, 4.4408920985006262e-16)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py:168: AccuracyWarning:    maxiter (50) exceeded. Latest difference = 6.965869e-04
 AccuracyWarning)
(3.107110439388189, 0.00069658693569163432)

(2.0, 2.220446049250313e-14)
(3.141592653589564, 6.200200353134733e-10)
```

Firstly, as may be seen, the answer depends on whether 1/2 or 0.5 is given in the exponent: why is that so?

Secondly, the result depends on the routine chosen; can someone explain why FORTRAN's QUADPACK gets the right answer but the Gaussian quadratures miss the result completely?

*Note*: A similar question is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986588/tanh-sinh-quadrature-numerical-integration-method-converging-to-wrong-value) but does not address the two specific questions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @gjdanis points out, in python 2.7, `1/2` is `0` (unless you include `from __future__ import division` in your code).

Your integrand has singularities at 1 and -1.  `fixed_quad` and `quadrature` perform Gaussian quadrature with a weighting function `w(x) = 1`, so those singularities are not handled well.

`fixed_quad` is not adaptive (hence the name).  The default order is 5.  You'll have to increase the order (by a lot) to get a reasonable approximation:

```
In [179]: print fixed_quad(lambda x: 1/(1 - x**2)**(0.5), -1, 1, n=100)
(3.124265558250825, None)

In [180]: print fixed_quad(lambda x: 1/(1 - x**2)**(0.5), -1, 1, n=2000)
(3.1407221810853478, None)
```

`quadrature` simply calls `fixed_quad` with increasing order (up to a maximum given by the `maxiter` argument) until the difference between successive integral estimates is sufficiently small.  The warning that is printed tells you that the maximum order was reached without meeting the desired error tolerance.  The default for `maxiter` is 50; you'll need to increase `maxiter` to get better results.  For example, here's the result with `maxiter=200`:

```
In [2]: print quadrature(lambda x: 1/(1 - x**2)**(0.5), -1, 1, maxiter=200)
/Users/warren/local_scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py:183: AccuracyWarning: maxiter (200) exceeded. Latest difference = 4.353464e-05
  AccuracyWarning)
(3.1329074742380407, 4.3534643496823122e-05)
```

If you use `maxiter`, you should also make judicious use of `miniter`.  `quadrature` naively starts at `miniter` and increases the order by 1 until the error estimate is small enough or `maxiter` is reached.

To learn more about how `fixed_quad` and `quadrature` work, take a look at the source code: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py

As you point out, `quad` is a wrapper of the Fortran library QUADPACK.  This code is far more sophisticated than the simple Gaussian quadrature used by `fixed_quad` and `quadrature`.

Answer (score 3):

In python 2.7 (which you're using) integer division is default. This means 1/2 will evaluate to 0. If you want to use floating point division, add `from __future__ import division` to the top of your code.

Comment: Thanks @gjdanis, that indeed answers my first question.

Comment: @MaviPranav: happy to help! happens to me all the time!